# Django 'ifequal' with string comparisons

Tags: python, django

I currently am trying to compare two strings with an `ifequal` tag in Django. The current issue is that although the two strings are equal, Django does not run everything inside the if statement.

html

```html
    {% for group in groups %}
        <h1 class="inverted-popout">{{ group.name }}</h2>
        <div class="sheets">
            {% for sheet in sheets %}
                {% ifequal sheet.sheetGroupValue group.sheetGroupName %} <!-- This is the issue -->
                    <div class="sheet popout">
                        <h2><a href="{% url 'sheets:detail' slug='sheet.slug' slug=sheet.slug %}">
                            {{ sheet.name }} {{ sheet.hitPoints }} / {{ sheet.maxHitPoints }}
                        </a></h2>
                        <h3>{{ sheet.sheetGroupValue }}</h3>
                        <p><i>Lvl {{ sheet.level }} ({{ sheet.xp }})</i></p>
                        <p>{{ sheet.Class }}</p>
                        <p>{{ sheet.background }}</p>
                        <p>{{ sheet.race }}</p>
                    </div>
                {% endifequal %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```py
def sheetList(request):
    sheets = Sheet.objects.all().order_by('name')
    groups = SheetGroup.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'sheets/sheetList.html', { 'sheets': sheets, 'groups': groups })
```

models.py

```py
class SheetGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def sheetGroupName(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Sheet(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    sheetGroup = models.ManyToManyField(SheetGroup)

    slug = models.SlugField(default="")

    # there's a bunch of fields but they do not contribute to the error

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def sheetGroupValue(self):
        groups = ''
        for group in self.sheetGroup.all():
            groups += group.name + " "

        return groups
```

Here is a sheet
[image: example sheet]

Here is a group[image: example group]

And in the end Django says they are not equal (the `<div class="sheet popout">` does not appear.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Sheet.sheetGroupValue()` is returning strings with a trailing space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sheetGroupValue()` is currently returning a space at the end, so the two strings aren't equal.

```py
def sheetGroupValue(self):
        groups = ''
        for group in self.sheetGroup.all():
            groups += group.name + " "

        return groups[0:len(groups)-1]
```